How to get Fabricjs to resize an image
I want to use the Fabric Canvas library, to resize an image uploaded into my browser - and then let the resized image be downloaded again.
The upload button works fine, but it doesn't show the image on my canvas.  I can't see any errors in the developer tools window, or in my Visual Studio Code editor.
Can anyone point me in the right direction please?
Thanks, Mark
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Fabric.js Image Resize</title>
<!--<script src="index.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/650/index.min.js"> 
</script>
<style>
    #canvas-container {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<div id="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="fabric-canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    // Initialize Fabric canvas
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric-canvas', {
        width: 1050,  // 105mm in pixels for 100LPCM (10 pixels per mm)
        height: 1050,
    });

    // Function to handle image upload
    document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                fabric.Image.fromURL(e.target.result, function(img) {
                    // Set image scaling and size to fit within 105mm x 105mm
                    img.scaleToWidth(1050); // 105mm * 10 pixels/mm for 100LPCM
                    img.scaleToHeight(1050);
              
                    // Clear existing canvas and add resized image
                    canvas.clear();
                    canvas.add(img);
                    canvas.centerObject(img);
                    canvas.renderAll();
                });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    });
 </script>
</body>
</html>


Use like this
fabric.Image.fromURL(e.target.result).then( function(img) {
}
